# qtableView автоматический перенос строк

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно реализовать автоматический перенос строк в qtableView с фиксированным размером столбцов?

```
model = new QSqlTableModel(this,db);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setTable("TableEventBalancer");
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
QFont font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());
font.setPointSize(12);
ui->tableView->setFont(font);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnToContents(0);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnToContents(1);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Fixed);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Fixed);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->tableView->setWordWrap(true);
ui->tableView->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideRight);
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("number"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("ID"));
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("_date"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Дата"));
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("text"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Событие"));
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, как сделать перенос текста в ячейке, если не влезает в ширину столбца?

Comment: Да перенос в ячейки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Qt по каким-то причинам откровенно плохо реализовано вычисление размеров элементов ItemView, особенно в случае деревьев. Согласно документации, должен работать `setWordWrap(true)`, но не работает. Если вызвать`setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideNone)` и установить `QStyledItemDelegate` для проблемных столбцов, в некоторых простых случаях перенос все же сработает, но только если ширина столбцов действительно фиксирована (в вашем случае может сработать). На практике, как минимум при появлении полосы прокрутки возникают проблемы, т.к. размеры ячеек не обновляются при изменении размера viewport. Даже если перенос заработает, неразрывные пробелы игнорируются (это проблему особенно сложно решить), иногда возникают проблемы с кириллицей.

Стандартных решения два: использование `ItemWidget` с установкой `QLabel`  в качестве содержимого, и использование делегата. Первый вариант не для вашего случая, но иногда полезен. Для второго варианта нужно создать наследник `QStyledItemDelegate` и переопределить `sizeHint` и `paint`. Причем при правильной реализации `sizeHint`, стандартная реализация `paint` может сработать корректно, если это простой текст, а не html.

Для реализации делегата есть два подхода. Можно пытаться использовать `QTextDocument` для отрисовки и`QFontMetrics` для определения размера. Если ширина ячейки известна, определить высоту не сложно.  `QTextDocument` также умеет отображать html, в отличие от стандартной реализации.
Другой вариант - создать фиктивный QLabel без родителя с `setWordWrap(true)`, и в реализации делегата вызывать `label->setFixedWidth(columnWidth); label->setText(text);` и использовать его `sizeHint` для определения размера и `render` для отрисовки. QLabel  тоже умеет в html.
В обоих случаях нужно не забыть учесть отступы, которые получаются из стилей, `QStyle::pixelMetric` и `QStyle::drawControl`.

Ну и это все работает только с текстовыми ячейками. Если у вас, например, появляется ячейки с checkbox, все становится сложнее. Я в таких случаях стараюсь использовать `QStyledItemDelegate` для ячеек с checkbox, и многострочный делегат для остального.

Помимо текста в ячейках, проблема может возникнуть с текстом в заголовках. Решается аналогичным образом, но переопределением `QHeaderView`.

Для того, чтобы учесть изменение ширины столбцов при появлении полосы прокрутки, приходится устанавливать `eventFilter` на `viewport`, и при изменении его размера вызывать dataChanged для всех ячеек, что, мягко говоря, неэффективно, но работатет.

Comment: Можно попросить пример с 'QStyledItemDelegate'?

Comment: @zhilenkov Доступная мне реализация является частью коммерческого проекта, и при этом костыльная.  За основу лучше брать http://3adly.blogspot.com/2013/09/qt-custom-qlistview-delegate-with-word.html

Comment: спасибо за статью помогло. Есть вопрос, как можно изменить размер столбцов в paint ?

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне помог метод `resizeRowsToContents()`, только вызывать его надо не при создании таблицы, а каждый раз после добавления элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, у меня есть свой QTableView (4.8.1) и там wrap работает как надо. Естественно надо размер ячейки делать по высоте побольше:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот уменьшаем ширину столбца и происходит перенос текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

resizeRowsToContents() у меня не используется.

Делегат для "длинная строка для примера" тоже не используется, то есть делегат штатный по умолчанию.

Кстати какой Qt (версия)?

Чтобы выяснить проблему можно отладчиком пройтись по QTableView::paintEvent(..) и все станет очевидным. Тут гадать бессмысленно, надо смотреть код Qt, как он выполняется.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]